# How to build an APK with the help of the build tool and task : gradle assembleDebug and what content needed in the build.gradle.kts file

Tags: java, windows, gradle, apk

I am just new to the Gradle tool and appreciate some help to be able to build an APK with gradle and CLI commands.

I can not use the Android Studio due to memory issue, so I need to find a way to manually build the APK.

What is needed in the `build.gradle.kts` file to be able to use the build tool for windows 10: `gradle assembleDebug`

My `build.gradle.kts` file looks like this now:

```
plugins {
    java
}

tasks.named<Jar>("jar") {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.gradlehero.languageapp.SayHello"
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me with an example.

I want to add something like this to the `build.gradle.kts` file but it seems not to be working:

`task assembleDebug(type: Assemble) { debuggable true`

Am I missing a lot of things or is above task enough to be able to build the APK file?

I have already successfully built these files:

- `gradle compileJava`
- `gradle processResources`
- `gradle jar`

but I also want to build the APK file.

Grateful for any help!
Per